# not able to click on a button for scraping using selenium and python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

[THIS IS THE BUTTON CODE WHICH I WANTED TO CLICK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27SUX.png)

I  used this code.

```
login_btn1 = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('button')
login_btn1.submit()
```

but they are showing the error:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'submit'

can someone help me with this please.Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

By using `find_elements_by_tag_name` you are looking for **all** `'button'` elements which will return a list.

You need to replace this with `find_element_by_tag_name` to retrieve a single `'button'` element. (this will be the first button element found)

Alternatively, in the likely situation that there is more than one button on the page, you can select by class name using `find_element_by_class_name('cdp-view-all-button')` or another method from the [selenium docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html).

Comment: findElements return list not array.

Answer (score 0):

When you write this :

```
login_btn1 = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('button')
```

Now `login_btn1` is a list of **Web Element**. you can have method which are applicable for list.

Since you want to click on button and button is a web element. you can't do `login_btn1.click()` .

If you want to click on a single button, first you have to find the locator then there are multiple ways to click on it such as :

```
 button =   WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-track-app='discovery']")))  
 button.click()
```

If the provided **xpath** is Unique in **DOM** then the above code would work.